# Define a new align environment with custom numeration

Tags: numbering, align

I am writting a report and I have multiple systems of equations. I want to avoid have too big numbers (Equation 4.200 for example) and I dont want to link the numbering to the chapter or the section.

I want a personalized align enviroment that enummerates the equations as:

(A1)

(A2)

(A3)

The first time I use it and

(B1)

(B2)

(B3)

The second time I use  and so on.

The normal numeration of the usual align enviroment or equation enviroment should not be afffected.

I have been trying for some hours but none of the answers seems to work :(

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can locally change the equation counter (restoring it at the end). This also behaves well with `\label` and `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{alphalign}
\renewcommand{\thealphalign}{\Alph{alphalign}}
\newcounter{alphalignsavedequation}

\newenvironment{alphalign}
 {%
  \setcounter{alphalignsavedequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \counterwithin*{equation}{alphalign}%
  \stepcounter{alphalign}%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thealphalign\arabic{equation}}%
  \align
 }
 {\endalign\setcounter{equation}{\value{alphalignsavedequation}}}

\begin{document}

An equation
\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}
An alignment with alpha
\begin{alphalign}
0&=0\\
1&=1\\
2&=2
\end{alphalign}
Another equation
\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}
Another alignment with alpha
\begin{alphalign}
0&=0\\
1&=1\\
2&=2
\end{alphalign}
Another equation
\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code `\let`s the `equation` counter to another counter called `selfalign` within the newly-defined environment (group) `selfalign`. Since the `\let` is scoped/temporary within the group, it reverts to the original definition afterwards. [`alphalph`](//ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) is used to ensure the `selfalign` counter prefix can roll over beyond `Z`, if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,alphalph}
\newcounter{selfalignprefix}
\newcounter{selfalign}[selfalignprefix]

\renewcommand{\theselfalignprefix}{\AlphAlph{\value{selfalignprefix}}}
\renewcommand{\theselfalign}{\theselfalignprefix\arabic{selfalign}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{selfalign}
  {\let\c@equation\c@selfalign% Make equation counter point to the selfalign counter
   \stepcounter{selfalignprefix}% Step the prefix counter
   \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theselfalign}% Update equation counter representation
  \align}
  {\endalign}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x) \\ g(x) \\ h(x)
\end{align}

\begin{selfalign}
  f(x) \\ g(x) \\ h(x)
\end{selfalign}

\begin{align}
  f(x) \\ g(x) \\ h(x)
\end{align}

\begin{selfalign}
  f(x) \\ g(x) \\ h(x)
\end{selfalign}

\end{document}
```